# Laravel Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have old project which built using Laravel 4.2.I am getting following **error**

> PDOException (1045)
>       SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have googled and tried every think but i couldn't able to fix it

**.env** file

```
APP_KEY=az9tq5VHQCV9g5m2CsgY89jtijrCMgEA
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=billing
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=1234
```

**database.php**

```
'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'billing',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => '1234',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
```

[image]

Can any one guide me where m doing wrong ?

Note:  Before asking question i tried by updating composer update as well as most of the stackoverflow answers.

**Updated**

I have tested this connection by creating php file

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "1234";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

i will get Connected successfully message

Comment: it might feel bit dumb to ask but did you try restarting your server ? and instead of using xampp can you use laravel inbuilt server and test it ?

Comment: @user3103915. i have restarted server.but i didn't tried laravel inbuilt server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel 4.x doesn't even support ENV files. You just have to see whether settings in ./config/[env name]/database.php are correct.

Answer (score 54):

My error was `Laravel Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

and I only got this error at my host site.

In .env I changed:

```
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

to:

```
DB_USERNAME='user'
DB_PASSWORD='password'
```

Worked for me!

Comment: This was the solution even in Laravel 8.41.0. Amazing.

Comment: Yeah, worked like a charm in Laravel 8 and cPanel. Thanks

Comment: Do a `php artisan config:clear` after changing the .env file so that the new values will be fetched from the .env file.

Comment: I can't believe this was the issue. Nice job! Thanks!

Comment: I have struggled for so long. ANd this here is what fixed it for me.

Comment: This will specifically solve the issue if you have special characters at the start or end of the `user` and `password` values.

Answer (score 14):

`DB_HOST="localhost"` worked for me.

---

And to be safe, wrap `.env` variables in double quotes to avoid ENV errors:

```
DB_USERNAME="root"
DB_PASSWORD="#Password"
```

These will give errors: `DB_PASSWORD=#Password`, `DB_PASSWORD=I have spaces`

`#` is a start of a comment and is exactly the same as `//`

Answer (score 8):

Run `php artisan serve` after configure `.env`, not before.

Answer (score 4):

The error says it all, Laravel can't connect to a DB. Check [priveleges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html) and make sure the DB exists. Also, try to connect to a DB with a client, like MySQL Workbench using same login and password. This will give a hint about what you can do to fix this. If you can't do this, it's not a Laravel issue.

Comment: Ya i have all Privileges. I am using xampp server. Even i have tested that connection .

Comment: So, you're able to connect to this DB using same login/password/host with MySQL Workbench or similar client? If yes, try to run `php artisan config:clear` command to clear configuration cache.

Comment: ya.even i tried before itself that command. i have restarted xampp server also

Comment: What's value of `'default'` option in`database.php` config? Do you have `DB_CONNECTION` in an `env` file?

Comment: 'default' => 'mysql',

Comment: DB_CONNECTION is not defined. but you can check my question what i have in .env file

Comment: `php artisan config:clear` solved my problem. Not sure but it had different credentials with which it was accessing the DB from the ones in my .env. Thank you, @AlexeyMezenin

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same problem on a new Laravel install.
The problem was that I was connecting to my ubuntu localhost mysql server instead of to the vagrant box's mysql server that was on it's own ip address '192.168.10.10'.
I changed over to that and all worked a charm :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm test in Laravel 5.6.33 and i see this error: **"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'"**, but the username and password is **correct**. 
  In this version i think of this is a BUG, i change DB_HOST, from 127.0.0.1 to localhost and works!

<strike>DB_HOST=127.0.0.1</strike> (before) 
 
 DB_HOST=localhost (after)

Answer (score 3):

Try In .ENV

```
APP_ENV=local
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=billing
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=1234
```

And **Delete** Cache Files From **Root/boostrap/chache/files**
and Run The App

Answer (score 2):

Try This

.env file

```
APP_ENV=local

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=billing
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=1234
```

config/database.php

```
default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),


'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST','localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE','billing'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME','root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', '1234'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        )
```

Else checkout the .env file and check the connection

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem. You should add "" to the DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD
So,

- Step 1: DB_USERNAME="root" DB_PASSWORD="1234"
- Step 2: Run "php artisan config:clear"
- Step 3: Run "php artisan cache:clear"

Answer (score 2):

please delete config file located at bootstrap/cache/config.php
it will be autogenerated when you run php artisan config:cache command
it will work

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem when learning laravel using homestead, the problem happened when I try to open a page. It tried to connect to database but got rejected, although I can connect to the database using mysql command line.
The problem was I had wrong assumption that since homestead forward web server request from guest to host, the same thing is also same with myqsl, but apparently it is not.
Homestead has it's own mysql service, so my problem was fixed by:
- **homestead ssh** into the guest machine
- **mysql -u root -p** to connect to mysql command line, default password is "secret"
- create the database, but you need to change your password first, just change into the same password as in mysql root's password in your host machine for convenience
- exit the mysql cli and 
- **php artisan migrate** to create the tables
- refresh your browser, now it should be able to connect to your db

Answer (score 1):

**Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

> The error was coming? The possible reason is your database
>   connection.If the database is not connect then throw the error.
>
> So Check the database releted all things and If all things is correct.
>
> If not solved then change

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 TO DB_HOST=localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `.env` is using the correct port number. If you're using `phpMyAdmin` this is how is setup:

```
MariaDB defaults to 3306
```

and

```
MySQL defaults to 3308
```

So change your `.env` to use port 3308 for MySQL. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I changed this line  DB_HOST=127.0.0.1  in .env to DB_HOST=localhost and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, the password is the major issue in such communication, see my picture below, i solved it after changing password, php artisan serve and then reloading my view. It worked.

please login to mysql or phpmyadmin and change your password.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vaP9.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds kind of obvious, but check the credentials of the database.

Answer (score 0):

For me something was wrong in the env file.  So I created a fresh installation, copied the env file from there and updated the credentials and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using docker and still having issues with user access denied issues, you may want to try starting over fresh with the DB, which is was what it took for me.

First, I figured out where my DB data volumes were being stored in my docker-compose.yml file, which ended up being here: [app root dir]/docker/db/data/

```
    db:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_db
    image: mysql:8.0
    ports: 
        - 33060:3306
    volumes: 
        - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
```

Then I ran this in the app root directory to remove all the docker containers.

```
docker-compose rm -v
```

Next I navigated to the DB data files and removed all of them:

```
cd ~/[app root dir]/API/docker/db/data
sudo rm -rf ./*
```

Finally, I started up the containers and was then able to connect with my database user credentials.

```
docker-compose up --build --force-recreate --no-deps
```

REFERENCE: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/51

Answer (score 0):

If the username and password are correct and the problem still persists, try clearing the cache using the following method

```php
Route::get('/clear-cache', function () {
   Artisan::call('cache:clear');
   Artisan::call('route:clear');`
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Laravel 6 just set secret instead of empty space.

```
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```