# When I type "php artisan migrate" in terminal, I see error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

When I type "php artisan migrate" in terminal I see the error below:

```
In Connection.php line 664:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations)           



In Connector.php line 67:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I'm using mac and Mamp Pro,

**Some other informations: **
php artisan serve => Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8000

.env file =>

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=1234
```

In phpMyAdmin top of all things writed =>
Server: localhost:8889

Local host address when mamp pro ran =>
http://localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin/

In phpMyAdmin =>
DB name: laravel
Username: root
Pass: 1234

Comment: php artisan config:clear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error: : 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Comment: May the following links will help you https://superuser.com/questions/603026/mysql-how-to-fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39035201/laravel-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-in-larav

Comment: what is your db password? in mysql its default blank....

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your credentials cannot connect to the defined sql host.

Ideas:

1. Can you connect with your db credentials using Sequel Pro? https://www.sequelpro.com.
2. Be sure you grant laravel db permissions for your user.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing
`DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`
to
`DB_HOST=localhost`