# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in laravel

Tags: laravel

I delete a row number 5 which have id number 5, then i add another row but the id nummber proceed to 6 which have AUTO_INCREMENT. I adjust the auto_increment to 5 in Operations in phpmyadmin but when i came back to my app I got this error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `users` where `id` = 2 limit 1) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\resources\views\inc\navbar.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\resources\views\inc\navbar.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\resources\views\inc\navbar.blade.php)
```

Comment: Can you post your .env file? It seems you have not set the password correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in laravel 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39035201/laravel-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-in-larav)

Comment: APP_NAME=LSAPP
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:M72nbx4a2K9LBFca6BE8GToVVa8AV4g3agsnTHBkXmw=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=lsapp
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

Comment: Your configuration seems correct. do confirm the username/password are correct.

Answer (score 0):

check your password once again it is your password of phpmyadmin and try `DB_HOST=localhost`
and `APP_URL=`