# vagrant@homestead:~/Code/Laravel$ php artisan migrate:install failing

Tags: laravel, homestead, migrate

I'm running the artisan command in the title and getting the following on windows

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access
denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: create
table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary
key, `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default
character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
```

If I run `"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqlshow" -u root -p` it prompts for the password that's entered in my `.env` file and shows me SQL running i.e,

```
+--------------------+
|     Databases      |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| rm1                |
| sakila             |
| sys                |
| world              |
+--------------------+
```

I've tried quotes around usernames and passwords and all the privileges look ok on MySQL Workbench.

I'm using Laravel Framework 6.13.1. This is my first question here so apologies for any omissions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in laravel 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39035201/laravel-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-in-larav)

Comment: If you are using Laravel Homestead, make sure you are running the `php artisan migrate` command from your Vagrant box (SSH into your box first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For homestead you want to make sure you run artisan commands in the vagrant box, run `vagrant ssh` to ssh into your vagrant box. Depending on your install you might have to `cd` into your project folder. On a default install you can do `cd "code/{YourProjectDIR}"`. In here you can run your artisan commands.

Note:
Homestead creates a database for you, with default credentials
Username: homestead
Password: secret

Answer (score 0):

Your database setting is not correct in .env file. Please correct the connection setting and then try to run command.

```
php artisan migrate
```

Please find the .env file into root directory and set your database credentials as set into your phpmyadmin.

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=database_name
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

if these steps not helping then text me here.